# R: How to add vector in one list to another by parallel (with reproducible example)

Tags: r, vector

I am gonna add each element of one list to another in parallel (a.k.a, where element of list_1 are added to element of list_2 in parallel). I used lapply for this but could not get right one. I bet there is must be easy way to do this.

this is my reproducible example:

```
 list_1 <- list('a'=c(1,1,1), 'b'=c(1,1,1,1))
 list_2 <- list('a_'=c(1,0,0), 'b_'=c(1,1,0,0))
```

my desired output(just manually sketch my expected output like this):

```
output <- list('a'= c(2,1,1), 'b'=c(2,2,1,1))
```

How can I get this result? please help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to do it,

```
mapply('+', list_1, list_2)
#$a
#[1] 2 1 1

#$b
#[1] 2 2 1 1
```

Comment: Or `Map` (same syntax).

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works